# segmentation fault in UNIX stop&wait protocol

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault

Hi I am currently writing a C program in UNIX to model a socket stop & wait protocol for school. I am constantly getting a segmentation error when i enter 4 arguments into the command line. if i enter more or less than 4 then i get the correct error thrown. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 6500
#define MAX_LINE 256

int
main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
        FILE *fp;
        struct hostent *hp;
        struct sockaddr_in sin, client;
        char *host;
        char ack[MAX_LINE], buf[MAX_LINE], fname[MAX_LINE];
        int s, i, rnum, drop;
        int8_t current, last = -1;
        int rval, slen, NFrames, len;

        long LenFile;
        struct timeval rectime;  //The struct timeval structure represents an elapsed time
        struct timeval zone;

        if (argc==4){
                host=argv[1];
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "usage: simplex-talk host\n");
             //fprintf(stderr, "hello");
                exit(1);
        }

        if (!hp) {
                fprintf(stderr, "simplex-talk: unknown host: %s\n", host);
                exit(1);
        }

        bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&sin.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
        sin.sin_port=htons(SERVER_PORT);

        if((s=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0){
                 perror("simplex-talk; socket");
                 exit(1);
        }

        // create file request
        sprintf(buf, "%s\0", argv[3]);

        if ((rval=sendto(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client)))< 0) {
printf("sjkdfj");
perror("writing on datagram socket");
        }
        system("date");
        printf("Sent request for file %s at time = %ld %ld\n", argv[3], rectime.tv_sec, rectime.tv_usec);

        bzero(ack,sizeof(ack));
        slen = sizeof(client);

    buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
    len = strlen(buf) + 1;
         //request to send, waiting....

        while ((rval = recvfrom(s,ack,sizeof(ack),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&slen))<0){
                perror("receiver recvfrom");
                printf(stderr, "hhhhhhhh");
}
          //get time
        if (gettimeofday(&rectime, &zone) < 0) {
                perror("getting time");
                exit(1);
        }
        if(ack[0] == '0'){
                printf("Received file not found, time = %ld %ld, File = \"%s\"\n", rectime.tv_sec, rectime.tv_usec, fname);
        }
        if(ack[0] == '1') {
                char ch[MAX_LINE];
                int i, j;
                for(i=2, j=0; ack[i] != ' '; i++, j++){
                        ch[j] = ack[i];
                }
                ch[i++] = '\0';
                LenFile=atoi(ch);
                for(j=0; ack[i] && ack[i] != '.'; i++, j++){
                        fname[j] = ack[i];
                }
                fname[i++] = '\0';
                strcat(fname, "client.txt");
                NFrames = LenFile / MAX_LINE + (LenFile % MAX_LINE == 0 ? 0:1);
                printf("Received, ack sent, time = %ld %ld\nfname = \"%s\"\n", LenFile = "%d\n", rectime.tv_sec, rectime.tv_usec, fname, LenFile);

                //file I/O (reads)
                fp=fopen(fname, "w");
                if(fp==NULL){
                        perror("Opening File for Writing");
                        exit(1);
                }
                printf("Opening File %s for writing\n", fname);
                drop = 0;

                for(i=0; i < NFrames; ){
                        bzero(ack,sizeof(ack));
                        while ((rval = recvfrom(s,ack,sizeof(ack),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&slen))<0){
                                perror("receiver recvfrom");
                        }
 //get time
                        if (gettimeofday(&rectime, &zone) < 0) {
                                perror("getting time");
                                exit(1);
                        }
                        current = ack[0];
                        if(current == last) {
                                printf("Duplicate frame %d received\n", last);
                                continue;
                        }
                        printf("Recieved Frame #%d at time = %ld %ld\n\nContent:\n%s\n", current, rectime.tv_sec, rectime.tv_usec, ack+1);
                        fputs(ack+1, fp);

                        //creating ack
                        bzero(buf,sizeof(buf));
                        sprintf(buf, "%c%s\0", current, "ackp");

                        //25% chance of loss is to call random()
                        rnum = random();
                        if((rnum%4) != 0) {
                                // get time
                                if (gettimeofday(&rectime, &zone) < 0) {
                                        perror("getting time");
                                        exit(1);
                                }
                                if ((rval=sendto(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client))) < 0) {
                                perror("writing on datagram socket");
                                }else{
                                        i++;
                                        last = current;
                                        printf("Sent Received Packet ACK for Frame %d at time = %ld %ld\n", current, rectime.tv_sec, rectime.tv_usec);
                                }
                        }else{
                                drop++;
                        }
                }
                 printf("Total Number of dropped frames is %d\n", drop);
                //get time
                if (gettimeofday(&rectime, &zone) < 0) {
                        perror("getting time");
                        exit(1);
                }
                fclose(fp);
                printf("Closing file for writing at time = %ld %ld\n", rectime.tv_sec, rectime.tv_usec);
        }
        //get time
        if (gettimeofday(&rectime, &zone) < 0) {
                perror("getting time");
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("Closing Socked %d for File \"%s at time = %ld %ld\n", ntohs(client.sin_port), fname, rectime.tv_sec, rectime.tv_usec);
        close(s);
}
```

Comment: You check `hp` (like this: `if (!hp)`) but you never initialize `hp` to anything. It's a pointer and it points to who knows where? In other words, it's junk. And junk is unlikely to be `NULL`. So you continue further down and... *bam!*

Comment: Not sure what you mean.
isn't hp is initialized as a struct in the code? it does return the error if the hostname is incorrect. Note that i am running this over the school's virtual machine remotely.

Comment: Can you please show us a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/)?  The code you have posted (a) does not compile and, (b) is cluttered with unused variables presumably unrelated to your actual problem of argument counting and variable initialization.

Comment: I mean that you never make `hp` point to anything. It's a pointer. Where does it *point*? You never make it point anywhere in the code you show here. And yet, you test it... You *seem* to be testing something against `NULL` without having initialized that something to anything. So in one run, the something may be `NULL` and in another it may be `potato`. Good luck debugging ;)

Comment: @pilcrow yeah it is because I didn't post the entire code. I can do it if you wish.

Comment: @JonathanLee it helps to post the code you want help with. Solar flare activity is causing problem with our crystal balls today. You understand...

Comment: hahaha here ya go i did with an edit, thanks for all your help.

Comment: In addition to @NikBougalis point about not initializing `hp` before testing it with `if (!hp)`, there's the bit where you `bcopy(hp->h_addr, ...)`. The test may "safely" fail because, as pointed out, `hp` is likely to have a random-ish non-zero value, but dereferencing that value as source and length for `bcopy()` is likely to create unexpected values in your `sin` structure, which it appears that you then completely ignore, in favor of the entirely uninitialized `client` structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *first* problem is here:

```
bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&sin.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
```

Where does `hp` point to? It's a pointer that you haven't initialized and it points to some random area in memory. Accessing some random area in memory that doesn't belong to you is bad. Don't do it.

Comment: ok i edited it to point to something I think.
        if (argc==4){
                host=argv[1];
  hp = gethostbyname(host);
        }

Comment: Not bad! Not great (you still don't give a sensible default value to `hp` but you `exit` if you don't set it so let's not nitpick) but not bad. So... now... tell... what happens? Don't keep us in suspense.

Comment: alright no segmentation error! woohoo! but not outta the ballpark yet. now im getting a datagram socket error.

writing on datagram socket: Invalid argument
Wed Mar 13 14:29:18 PDT 2013
sjkdfjSent request for file go at time = 140734746993392 217545979656

Comment: So now, to your *next* problem: You never initialize `client` and `rectime` to anything either. They have space allocated for them, but that space is full of junk. Who knows what address `client` contains? Yet you try to send data to it. Please repeat after me: "**I, Jonathan Lee, will initialize variables to contain the data I need them to contain before I use them.**"

Comment: haha thanks nik. "I, Jonathan Lee, will initialize variables to contain the data I need them to contain before I use them."

part of this code has been provided by the teacher so we are supposed to build upon it. thanks for letting me know about the errors though!

Comment: No worries. These sort of errors are frequent when you start programming. It'll get easier to spot them as you practice and code more. Good luck! And thanks for taking a bit of good-natured ribbing in stride :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note: `argc` contains the count of the arguments passed to your program + one for the program name.  So if you are running your program with 4 arguments, `argc = 5` and `if (argc==4)` will not be met.  If that doesn't fix the issue, what is the stack of the segfault?

Comment: Thanks Blake,
i do gcc client.c -o client
then client (hostname) f1.txt 6400
and i get a seg fault

Comment: Can you run this in gdb and give the stack trace of the crash?  If you  do `$ gdb client` then `run (hostname) f1.txt 6400` it should crash and you can run `where` to get the stack.  I'm assuming there's more to your program than you pasted here, right?

Comment: I ran it but it didn't crash: this is what I got back. you are correct there is more to the program but I didn't want to burden anyone with reading all of it haha.
(gdb) run geometry f1.txt 6400
Starting program:  geometry f1.txt 6400
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb) where
No stack.

Comment: It looks like you may not be running gdb correctly.  Take a look at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/ for a quick intro to how to figure out the stack when you get a seg fault.  That's definitely an essential skill for C/C++ development.  Once you get the stack (and line where it is failing) you should be able to spot the error.  If not, post the stack here with a more complete example.